# How to show more than one image using active reports, Which control I have to use. I will bind images dynamically

Tags: activereports

I need to display multiple images dynamically, Please help me which control I have to use for this, and how to bind the images dnamically

Comment: Can you please clarify your question.   The image control is what you would use to bind the image.   You would only get multiple images if the image is in a repeating header.   Please specify the type of report you are using PageReport or SectionReport.  Where is your image control placed.  What do you want the image to be bound to?

Comment: We are using Section report, we have multiple images for each question, we will show those images along with question in the report we are generating

Comment: is the number of images variable per question?   how does your data look like?   question, image1, image2, imageN...   or is it question with a related table or array of images?    is the image stored in the DB or just the path.   Controls in a report only repeat within their containing section, I need to know the shape of your data in order to suggest whether to use a group-section on question or a subreport to cause the image control to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Picture Box** control. for displaying Images dynamically you can write the following code in code behind

```
 public Image GetImageObject(string imagename)
      {
          try
           {
            string _imagepath = D:\reports\Source\xyz\Images\+ imagename;
            if (File.Exists( _imagepath)
            {
                return System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(_imagepath);
            }
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

and then just create a object to your report, for Example your      report Name is **rptExample**, suppose from BLL method,

```
  rptExample orptExample=new rptExample();
  orptExample.Logo=GetImageObject("Example.png");
  orptExample.Run();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Praveen,  This will work for showing one image, I want to bind more than one image dynamically

Comment: @RakeshReddy, Yes it works for one image but in Active reports you don't have specific control for showing for more than one image. Simple thing you can do is, Based on condition as per your requirement write the code and change the property  orptExample.Logo=GetImageObject("Example1.png");  of picture box and in other condition change it to  orptExample.Logo=GetImageObject("Example2.png"); and in other condition  orptExample.Logo=GetImageObject("Example3.png");. Only one picture box but based on conditions as per your requirement and code and You can bind multiple images dynamically.

Comment: We tried this but it is overriding the previous one

Comment: @RakeshReddy , Yes it overrides because we are using only one Picture Box control. Can you be more specific of what you are actually trying to do because i can help you.  As per my knowledge if you want to print one dynamic image on each page you can write the code in page header or footer so that for each page you will be getting different dynamic image in a single picture box control.